# c# WinForm DataGridView bind List in List

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I want to bind list (ProductList) to DataGridView, but one column is collection (Categories), but the DataGridView show "(Collection)" and not the content of List. I can't rewrite or change this ProductList class. How can i bind this Categories List column?

Here is the Binding:

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dataGridView1.ColumnCount = model.ColumnsNames.Length;
for (int i = 0; i < model.ColumnsNames.Length; i++)
{
    string columnName = model.ColumnsNames[i];
    dataGridView1.Columns[i].Name = columnName;
    dataGridView1.Columns[i].DataPropertyName = columnName;
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = model.Products;
```

Here is [ProductModel](https://github.com/XiaoFaye/WooCommerce.NET/blob/master/WooCommerce/Product.cs) and the data source of grid is `List<Product>`:

```
public class Product
{
    //...

    /// <summary>
    /// List of product categories names (string). 
    /// In write-mode need to pass a array of categories IDs (integer)
    /// (uses wp_set_object_terms())
    /// </summary>
    public List<object> categories { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

I don't want to use sub-grid, i just want to show the property as a string in a TextBoxColumn something like this: CollectionElement1, CollectionElement2, etc.

It's not my class, actually just a reference. So I cant change it anywhere.

Comment: What's your expectation? How do you want to show a property of type Collection or List? If you think about something like a `Sub-Grid` or the feature which `Grid` control had and used to show relations in a grid, No, `DataGridView` doesn't have such feature. You can buy a 3rd-party grid control which support such feature. Also as an option you can just use a `Button` column and open a form containing the collection, when the user clicks on button.

Comment: I dont want to use sub-grid, i just want to show the property as a string in a TextBoxColumn something like this: CollectionElement1, CollectionElement2, etc.

Comment: "public List<object> categories { get; set; }"

Comment: Okey. Its not my class, acuallyjust a reference. So i cant change it anywhere. That List<object> give me a list with strings (this is what i see when i debug) . no more

Comment: Share the codes for models.

Comment: Its a ProductList type.
ProductList : List<Product>

https://github.com/XiaoFaye/WooCommerce.NET
this is what i use. my model just do the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`CellFormatting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx) event of `DataGridView` to provide a friendly representation of `categories` property:

```
void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    //Use zero based index of the cell that contains categories
    var cell= 3;

    if (e.ColumnIndex == cell && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        var categories = (List<object>)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[cell].Value;
        e.Value = string.Join(", ", categories.Select(x => x.ToString()));
    }
}
```

In this case, `categories` contains `List of product categories names (string).` So selecting `ToString()` is OK. But for a case of `List<SomeClass>`, you either should override `ToString` of `SomeClass` or select one of it's properties.

As another option you can shape the result of query using a new `ViewModel` or using anonymous type, but in the current situation which `Product` model doesn't belong to you and it has lot's of properties, previous solution is the most simple option.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = (from p in model.Products 
                            select string.Join(", ", p.categories.ToArray())).ToList();
```